# Issue with shared preferences with Long and Int using generics in Kotlin/Android

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I am trying to create a Flow based on shared preferences properties. To achieve this, I have defined two functions:

```
fun <T> getPreferenceAsFlow(keyValue: String, defValue: T?) = callbackFlow {
    val transformedKey = toKey(keyValue)
    val listener = SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { _, key ->
        if (key == transformedKey) {
            trySend(preferenceValueFlow<T?>(keyValue, defValue))
        }
    }

    mSharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener)

    if (mSharedPreferences.contains(transformedKey)) {
        send(preferenceValueFlow<T?>(keyValue, defValue)) // if you want to emit an initial pre-existing value
    }
    awaitClose { mSharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener) }
}.buffer(Channel.UNLIMITED)

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
private fun <T> preferenceValueFlow(keyValue: String, defValue: T?): T? {
    return when (T::class) {
        String::class -> getString(key = keyValue, defValue as String?) as T?
        Boolean::class -> getBoolean(key = keyValue, defValue?.let { it as Boolean } ?: false) as T?
        Int::class -> getInteger(key = keyValue, defValue as Int?) as T?
        Long::class -> getLong(key = keyValue, defValue as Long?) as T?
        else -> {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Preference type not supported: ${T::class.java.name}")
        }
    }
}
```

But when I define the variable flow like this:

`val lastAppDataUpdateDate: Flow<Long?> = securePrefs.getPreferenceAsFlow("key", null)`

I am expecting to get a Long, but instead I have a Int, so I have a NumberFormatException.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlKFg.png)

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong without success.
Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Returned data should be Long instead for Int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private fun <T> preferenceValueFlow(keyValue: String, defValue: T?): T? {
    return when (T::class) {
```

You can't do that.  Due to type erasure, it won't know the class of T at runtime.  To make it work you need a reified inline function.  See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters.

Or since you're passing in a value, you could do defValue::class.  But make sure that whenever you call this and want a long, you pass in 1L instead of 1, so it uses a Long.  The default is integer.  And null would never work, because null could be any of those types.

Just to add-  you shouldn't really be doing this as a generic at all.  If you need to check the type inside your generic function, you almost certainly shouldn't be doing a generic function.  Here you should have N functions, one for each type.  Yes, you copy paste some code, but it avoids ugliness and all the type problems you're seeing here.  It only makes sense to do this as a generic function if it can actually take any type.